# What does "clarinettes vermicelles" mean?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, argot, littérature

In the following sentences: "Faut des choses qui tiennent au buffet... pas de **clarinettes** vermicelles", what does "**clarinettes**" mean in this case?

I suppose it's not the usual musical sense. Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Cela ressemble à un dialogue en argot du milieu du siècle précédent, si c'est le cas, cela n'a rien à voir avec la musique …  le vermicelle passe de dur et raide à mou après cuisson … je vous laisse deviner,  dans cette réplique *virile*, l'allusion faite avec le second mot recherché … et translittérer :-)

Comment: Hahaha merci ! maintenant j'ai peut-être une idée ;-)

Comment: We're missing a bit of context to know exactly what the author meant, but it's probably some kind of analogy. It would help if you could either give the reference or just what was the situation when he said that.

Answer (score 1):

Le "buffet" c'est de l'argot, ça désigne le ventre. "Quelque chose qui tient au buffet", c'est quelque chose qui est long à digérer, qui donnera beaucoup d'énergie.

En argot, une "clarinette" c'est un fusil (une arme à feu), mais encore en argot, le "fusil" c'est le ventre, l'estomac :
https://www.gastronomiac.com/argot_de_bouche/fusil/

Et donc l'expression "pas de clarinettes vermicelles" signifie "pas d'estomacs petits et fins comme des vermicelles".

Les vermicelles ce sont des pâtes très fines et très courtes, comme des très petits spaghettis.

PS : dans quel livre avez-vous trouvé ces expressions ?

Comment: Les « vermicelli » en italien sont des pâtes aussi longues que les spaghetti mais plus épais

Comment: En France, il y a une "soupe aux vermicelles" et les pâtes sont très courtes.

Comment: Merci, je l’ignorais !

Comment: @JamesSilipo En italien, on les appelle des *capellini*.

Comment: Ou bien « spaghetti rotti »

Comment: En effet les capellini sont longs comme les spaghetti